# A problem based on zeroes of a quadratic polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

If f(x)= ax^2 + bx + c has no real zeroes and (a + b + c) < 0, what is the sign of 'c'?

If the sign of 'a' was known, I could have easily determined the sign of 'c' with a rough sketch of a graph. But, in the question, the sign of 'a' is not given. Also, I think this fact might be used in the problem:- The discriminant of a quadratic polynomial is less than 0 iff it has no real zeroes. Will this observation help in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : $a+b+c<0$ means that $f(1)<0$. Now $f(x)$ always has the same sign for every $x$ (why ?) and you should be able to determine that sign ...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This hint is great.

Answer (score 0):

a and c will have same sign.

$ \frac {a+c}{2} < (ac)^\frac{1}{2} $